# Java - Using multiple datagramSockets and ports

Tags: java, networking, udp, port

I'm working on a multi-client/single-server application that uses UDP to communicate.
The reason for this is that I'm using multicasts and I'm streaming audio.

I haven't got a lot of experience in UDP/TCP and I'm not really sure if it's okay that I'm using several `DatagramSockets` with several different ports.
I have a couple of different objects that I need to send from one device to another, therefor I'm using one port for each type of object.

Is this okay? I already am using about 7 different ports now.
How can I use as minimum ports as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With multiple clients and one server, you could have all clients send data to the same port on the server. The server would read all information from one socket (which is reading data on that port). Each client that sends data can send metadata along with each payload identifying the user, so the server can discern which received packet belongs to who. I actually think that you can already see the address that a packet comes from using built in functionality however. You could use these addresses to identify different clients, however down the road you might need a more robust solution to make your implementation more secure.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing this now. The only thing I'm 'worried' about is the fact that I have about 7 or 8 ports that are continuesly being read. Is it better to use less sockets (and ports) or should this not be a problem? I think it could be a problem if there are other programs running that coincidentally use the same port.

Comment: No what I'm saying is, the server has one socket, which is bound to a port. All clients are sending data to that same port (and the same socket). So the server has one socket that is reading in everything. Thats 1 port being used, not 7 or 8. And if you are worried about the port being taken, make the server bind its socket to port 0, at which point it will randomly select an available port (which you must then communicate to your clients somehow).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in wardd's comments, there might be a session protocol.

Easy version:

1. The client sends a connect message to the server socket
2. The server instantiates a new socket for the session with random port (bound to port 0)
3. The server sends an accept message on the new socket
4. The client receives the new port / socket with the accept message
5. the session continues with the session private sockets

For more security, there might be a unique session id for the handshake (used in step 4.), the handshake messages might be authenticated or even asymmetrically encrypted, as it is done in TLS.